# MySQL Key Column does not exist in Create Table

Tags: mysql, create-table

When I issue this command:

```
CREATE TABLE userxxx(
    idxxx INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (idxxx)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

I get the error: Key column 'idxxx' doesn't exist in table. **Should this statement not work?**

I know I can add PRIMARY KEY right after AUTO_INCREMENT such as:

```
CREATE TABLE userxxx(
    idxxx INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

then the command runs but this subsequent command to reference idxxx as a foreign key fails:

```
CREATE TABLE Requestxxx(
  RequestId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  idxxx INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (idxxx) REFERENCES userxxx (idxxx)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

with the error:
*Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'idxxx' for constraint 'requestxxx_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'userxxx'*

Comment: I receive the same errors as you if I copy and paste your code in fiddle, but I can't understand the problem in it. I've just written the same things and it seems to work. https://dbfiddle.uk/UgId-pag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved. In this code fragment

```
CREATE TABLE userxxx(
    idxxx INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

there were actually one or more invisible characters between the beginning of the line and the column name idxxx!! When I deleted all whitespace preceding idxxx and added back in 4 spaces the code worked. I had copied this create table statement from another source and when I view that source with notepad++ it does not show any weird chars. I do not know where they came from. Shouldn't MySql warn or detect non-viewable chars in a column name?? Rather ironic: MySql did not report any syntax errors in the statement.

Comment: there were 4 EN SPACE (U+2002) characters. apparently those were treated as part of the identifier name, not whitespace, so mysql saw no need to warn.  if you copy those 4 characters to before the idxxx in the primary key, it works.

Comment: use a text editor for writing sql, not an editor designed for arbitrary documents!

Comment: Actually, I never used an editor at all. That Create Table was generated by ChatGPT, then pasted in an email and when I received the email I simply copied the code from Outlook and pasted in MySQL Workbench.